# Custom MKAnnotationView button is not work (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, mkannotationview

I have problem like this - [unsolved problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635311/custom-mqannotationview-button-is-not-clickable). My custom Annotation View button is not work when I click.

My code:

```
var confirm: MKAnnotationView = MKAnnotationView()

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView) {

        let annotation = view.annotation as! MapAnnotation

        let calloutSize: CGSize = CGSizeMake(250, 100)
        confirm = MKAnnotationView(frame: CGRect(x: -calloutSize.width/2, y: -calloutSize.height, width: calloutSize.width, height:calloutSize.height))

        confirm.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0
        confirm.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 243/255.0, green: 98/255.0, blue: 35/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        confirm.alpha = 0.9
        confirm.userInteractionEnabled = true

        let phoneButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 70, 200, 30))
        phoneButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        phoneButton.addTarget(self, action: "callToNumber:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        confirm.addSubview(phoneButton)

        view.addSubview(confirm)
    }

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didDeselectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView) {
    confirm.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

My target function

```
func callToNumber(sender: UIButton!){
    print("GO!!!")
}
```

But it doesn't print! If I put my view in `viewDidLoad()` its work fine! I think `@callToNumber` doesn't work because MKAnnotationView intercept it. How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32581049/mapkit-ios-9-detailcalloutaccessoryview-usage

Comment: Thats fine method. But iOS8 needs

Comment: iOS 9 is reportedly on over 70% of devices. I'd forget about worrying about iOS 8.